# HTML & JS - How to display a DIV which contains one text field more than once

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am new to development. Right now I have a requirement in a form as I need to display a field with Add and Remove buttons. If user clicks on Add button, app should display one more field. If user clicks on Remove button, app should hide the respective field.

Please suggest me how can I make a Text field to display more than once. Moreover I need get the text field data in PHP hence I should have different name for fields.

Thank you in advance!

Raja

Comment: you can use jquery or js to add fields dyanamically into dom. and you can use name of field as array, jus like name[ ]. refer this link too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709926/how-can-i-use-the-array-format-input-field-names-in-my-html-form-that-posts-to-p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be helpful for you.

html:

```
<h2><a href="#" id="addScnt">Add Another Input Box</a></h2>

<div id="p_scents">
<p>
    <label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label>
</p>
</div>
```

Css:

```
* { font-family:Arial; }
h2 { padding:0 0 5px 5px; }
h2 a { color: #224f99; }
a { color:#999; text-decoration: none; }
a:hover { color:#802727; }
p { padding:0 0 5px 0; }

input { padding:5px; border:1px solid #999; border-radius:4px; -moz-border-radius:4px; -web-kit-border-radius:4px; -khtml-border-radius:4px; }
```

javascript:

```
$(function() {
    var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
    var i = $('#p_scents p').size() + 1;

    $('#addScnt').live('click', function() {
            $('<p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i +'" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label> <a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
            i++;
            return false;
    });

    $('#remScnt').live('click', function() { 
            if( i > 2 ) {
                    $(this).parents('p').remove();
                    i--;
            }
            return false;
    });
 });
```

Thanks

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.