# Ruby on Rails: How to link two input fields and an object together when submitting form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, input, parameters, key-value

Hi there. I was wondering how I could link 2 input fields together with an object when submitting a form.

At present I have a food menu that contains many food items. For each item in the menu, I wish to have two input fields linked to it. A check-box to select the item and a number field to enter the quantity of the item required.

When I click submit I would like to be able to access the selected items in the controller to which they were sent to and then be able to display each item in a designated view.

I was able to send the quantity of only a single item through. However, when I entered quantities for many food items, the resulting hash in the params was empty.

Is there any way I could send the item(s) selected + quantities entered as a key-value pair in the params when I click submit.

**Edit(1):-**

I am currently able to send the food items as a key-value pair but I would like to only send those where the checkbox is ticked.

[Selecting food items and entering quantities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tkfu.png)

`Resulting parameters:
{"1"=>{"quantity"=>"2"}, "2"=>{"quantity"=>""}, "3"=>{"quantity"=>"1"}, "4"=>{"quantity"=>""}, "5"=>{"quantity"=>""}, "6"=>{"quantity"=>""}, "7"=>{"quantity"=>""}, "8"=>{"quantity"=>""}, "9"=>{"quantity"=>""}, "10"=>{"quantity"=>""}, "11"=>{"quantity"=>""}, "12"=>{"quantity"=>""}}`

Code:

```
<h2><u>Appetizers: -</u></h2>
<form action="/order/create" method="post">

    <input type="hidden" value="<%= form_authenticity_token %>" name="authenticity_token">

    <% @food.where(course: 'appetizer').each do |appetizer| %>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <%= appetizer.name %> - <%= number_to_currency(appetizer.price, :unit => "£") %>
                <input type="checkbox">
            </li>
                 <label for="<%= appetizer.id %>_quantity">Qty:</label>
                 <input type="text" 
                        name="<%= appetizer.id %>[quantity]" 
                        size="2" 
                        id="<%= appetizer.id %>_quantity">
        </ul>
    <% end %>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<br>

<%= link_to 'Back', menu_path %>
```

Comment: There are ways to do this.  Depending on how your models are structured `accepts_nested_attributes_for` may be your friend here.  However, we cannot really help you without your code.  Please [edit] to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates 
your problem would help you get better answers. Thanks!

Comment: Hi there, I just updated the question with my attempt. Is there anyway I could only post those items where the checkbox is ticked?

Answer (score 0):

You can get quick answers, if you include a code snippet. Coming to your question -
Have you used the array notation for the input element names?

```
<input type="text" name="textbox[]" />
```

Using this you can get two arrays - one array for checkbooks and other for text boxes..  this should be equivalent of having a  map.

See this
[Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709926/how-can-i-use-the-array-format-input-field-names-in-my-html-form-that-posts-to-p) which talks about similar problem.