# Include additional search variables when search is executed

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms

I have a basic search box I created to search a database. When a user submits their search terms, I would like to have it automatically attach additional terms to the search. The field "name" for the terms the user enters is "term". I have been able to add a hidden field that includes the additional search variables I want automatically attached when the user submits the form. The problem is the name for that field also has to be "term" for the search to work properly. When the search is submitted, the second "term" in the query string causes the search to not execute properly. Is there a way to pass additional "term" variables using a hidden field without passing the field name "term"? I've included an example below.  Any help is greatly appreciated - thanks in advance!

```
term=%28dog+OR+cat%29+AND+%28young+OR+old%29**&term**=AND+veterinarian
```

My form structure currently looks something like the following:

```
<form action="form link" class="class-name" id="search-form" method="get" target="_blank">
<div class="wrapper"><textarea class="query-box" id="query-box" name="term" value="" placeholder="text"></textarea></div>

<div class="wrapper-2">
<div class="class-name-2"><input id="id_term" name="term" value="AND (&quot;dog&quot;OR &quot;cat&quot;)" type="hidden"/></div>
    
<div class="button-wrapper"><button class="search-btn" type="submit"><span class="text"> Search </span></button></div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Did you try array of input field ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709926/how-can-i-use-the-array-format-input-field-names-in-my-html-form-that-posts-to-p

Comment: More information including the HTML and JavaScript code you tried might make this easier to evaluate here.

Comment: Thanks - I added some additional code.

Comment: @Yanis-git - thanks so much for the suggestion!  I gave that a try and didn't have any luck.  The second instance of "term" will always be the same, so I am trying to figure out a way to append that to whatever is submitted by the user. I think I might be in over my head - I appreciate your recommendation, however!

Comment: just to clarify, what you try to do is automatically concatenate the `textarea` content with the `value` of `hidden input` ? Also you confirm than you can't update the API Side to handle multiple criteria fields ?

Comment: @Yanis-git - Yes, both of those are correct.